# There's no 'sudo' command in Cygwin

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

Because there's no [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) command in [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), scripts that I want to run fail with

```
./install.sh: line N: sudo: command not found
```

What's the standard way for getting around this? Editing the scripts to remove `sudo`? Getting some `sudo`-like tool for Windows?

Comment: @dotancohen, I hope I picked the right one.

Comment: Looks like a good solution to me! Cygwin support has certain gotten better in the past five years!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090301/root-user-sudo-equivalent-in-cygwin

Comment: @Benj, I wonder why that question didn't get migrated here, too.

Comment: @JasonSundram indeed. Let me know if the answer is moved, I'll then update the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote the (rather simple) [TOUACExt](https://superuser.com/questions/741345/practical-closest-to-the-classical-linux-one-way-to-use-automate-sudo-for-cy) for [SUDO for CygWin](https://github.com/nu774/sudo-for-cygwin), a pre-beta shell script automation that approaches to the **behavior of classical** `sudo` for Linux:

- **Open and closes automatically** sudoserver.py when needed.
- Requests **UAC** Elevation Prompt.

**Installation** requires copying the four `.sh` scripts to some path directory, creating an alias and just a few more steps detailed in the thread.

**The results**: you type a single `sudo YourCommand` and you get the output of it, without having to worry about the rest of the process.

Answer (score 36):

One way is to create a fake "sudo" command with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

"$@"
```

This will allow the `install.sh` to continue, because sudo is found.

This doesn't elevate privileges like real sudo does. If you really need elevated privileges start cygwin shell with from an account with administrative privileges (XP) or r-click on cygwin.bat and *"run as administrator"* (Vista,Win7)

Comment: Just out of curiosity from someone who doesn't speak fluent `bash`: Why does this work? The manpage doesn't say anything about `$@` doing anything `sudo`-like. Instead it's just all arguments to the script. And wouldn't the quotes around it be superfluous in that case? Otherwise if you'd do a `sudo foo bar` then it tries executing `"foo bar"` as a single command which probably doesn't exist given that irrational fear of spaces on UNIX-like systems.

Comment: @Johannes: `"$@"` (when double-quoted) works differently from `"$*"`: it expands to a **separate** word for every positional variable. **Example:** If `$1 == "foo bar"` and `$2 == "baz"`, then `"$@"` is `"foo bar" baz` - one word for each parameter (unlike `"$*"`, which results in `"foo bar baz"` as one word). See manual of `bash`, section _Parameters_, subsection _Special parameters_. The end result of Peon's script is that it executes its arguments exactly as they were passed.

Comment: Ah, ok. And where does the `sudo` part come in? Above snippet doesn't do anything remotely in that direction, right?

Comment: @Johannes: In Unix, a real `sudo` would raise privileges from mortal to `root` before running the command. In Cygwin, there is no such thing, so Peon's fake script (which you're supposed to name `sudo`) just runs the command directly without changing its privileges. (This means you may need to run `./install.sh` as Administrator.)

Comment: Something really smart would be to write something involving `win32security.ImpersonateLoggedInUser()`, or at least `runas`, in order to actually raise privileges to Administrator... however, I'm stuck on XP and don't know if that works with UAC. Peon's solution is much simpler.

Comment: @grawity: `runas` should work, it doesn't rely on UAC and prompts for a password by itself. I was just confused why the script in the answer apparently didn't do what the name implied which I assumed was the goal. Sorry for my stupidity ;-)

Comment: +1. Note though that since the real `sudo` supports options this can break on occasions. A smarter wrapper script would have knowledge about those and strip them away to avoid breakage on invocations with options, e.g. `sudo -n`.

Comment: **Note:** newline in that script should be `0x0A`.

Answer (score 29):

I found the answer on [the cygwin mailing list](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-04/msg00651.html). To run `command` with elevated privileges in Cygwin, precede the command with `cygstart --action=runas` like this:

```
$ cygstart --action=runas command
```

**This will open a Windows dialogue box asking for the Admin password and run the command if the proper password is entered.**

This is easily scripted, so long as `~/bin` is in your path:

```
$ cat ~/bin/sudo
#!/usr/bin/bash
cygstart --action=runas "$@"

$ PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
$ chmod +x ~/bin/sudo
$ sudo elevatedCommand
```

Tested on 64-bit Windows 8.

Comment: The problem with the `cygstart` method is that it only works for Windows commands/programs. You can not do `sudo ls`. SUDO for CygWin is neat, but still lacks some good `sudo` command in it.

Comment: Thank you, Sopalajode. In what situation have you needed to use `sudo ls` in Cygwin?

Comment: Oh, no, @Dotancohen, it was just an example. You can use `sudo` for CygWin to run any Windows or CygWin command. It is very useful for me. But the more practical method I have found is this script wrapper for SUDO for CygWin I developed: http://superuser.com/questions/741345/practical-closest-to-the-classical-linux-one-way-to-use-automate-sudo-for-cy (still in Beta, but seems to work ). With it you can comfortably order things like `sudo net start vncserver`.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: That is absolutely terrific! Thank you for the post and the link.

Comment: curiously, this strips out `/bin` and `/usr/bin` from the `PATH`. It does successfully invoke emacs: `ShellExecute(NULL, "runas", "C:\cygwin64\bin\emacs-w32.exe", "(null)", "(null)", 1)` but then emacs cannot find `ls` for e.g. `M-x dired`, even after interactively restoring the PATH using `(setenv ...)`. Is there a trusted paths issue here?

Comment: tried almost everyother solution. this is the only one that worked

Answer (score 5):

Building on [dotancohen's answer](https://superuser.com/a/699281/40916) I'm using an alias:

```
alias sudo="cygstart --action=runas"
```

Works as a charm for external programs (not shell built-ins, though):

```
sudo chown User:Group <file>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sudo (Elevate) for Windows™

I do a lot of work on the command line in Windows™.

In Cygwin itself I believe you can run a root command with `su -c /the/cmd` as for sudo itself within Windows™ file-system elevating the user's permissions from the command line, If you are an administrator, this will work great for you. Otherwise, use runas and get admin's pass ;).

Now I cannot remember where we got this code but here it is. I hope it helps.

*BTW, the package we use to compile this was `gcc-mingw32`.*

```
$ i586-mingw32msvc-gcc sudo.c -o sudo.exe
# Put sudo.exe in /usr/bin or in your windows path (%homedrive%\windows)
#example:
$ sudo vi /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

/**
* (sudo for Windows™)
* @filename sudo.c
*/
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <wchar.h>


LPWSTR *mergestrings(LPWSTR *left, LPCWSTR right)
{
    size_t size = ( 1 + lstrlen(*left) + lstrlen(right) ) * sizeof(LPWSTR*);
    if ( *left ) {
        LPWSTR leftcopy = _wcsdup(*left);
        *left = (LPWSTR)realloc(*left, size);
        *left = lstrcpy(*left, leftcopy);
        *left = lstrcat(*left, right);
        free( leftcopy );
    }
    else
        *left = _wcsdup(right);
    return left;
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPSTR lpcommand, int nShowCmd)
{
    DWORD result = 0x2a;
    LPWSTR *argv = NULL;
    int argc = 0;
    if ( argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc) ) {
        if ( argc < 2 ) {
            LPWSTR usagemsg = NULL;
            usagemsg = *mergestrings(&usagemsg, argv[0]);
            usagemsg = *mergestrings(&usagemsg, TEXT(" <command_to_run> [arguments]"));
            MessageBox(NULL, usagemsg, TEXT("Usage:"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );
            LocalFree( argv );
            free( usagemsg );
            return ERROR_BAD_ARGUMENTS;
        }
        else {
            LPWSTR command = argv[1];
            LPWSTR arguments = NULL;
            int c;
            for ( c = 2; c < argc; c++ ) {
                arguments = *mergestrings(&arguments, argv[c]);
                arguments = *mergestrings(&arguments, TEXT(" "));
            }
            result = (DWORD)ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("runas"), command, arguments, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            LocalFree( argv );
            if ( arguments )
                free( arguments );
            switch ( result )
            {
                case 0:
                    result = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
                    break;

                case 27:
                case 31:
                    result = ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION;
                    break;

                case 28:
                case 29:
                case 30:
                    result = ERROR_DDE_FAIL;
                    break;
                case 32:
                    result = ERROR_DLL_NOT_FOUND;
                    break;
                default:
                    if ( result > 32 )
                        result = 0x2a;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        result = GetLastError();

    if (result != 0x2a) {
        LPWSTR errormsg = NULL;
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
                      NULL, result, 0, (LPWSTR)&errormsg, 0, NULL);
        MessageBox(NULL, errormsg, TEXT("Error:"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        LocalFree( errormsg );
        return result;
    }
    else
        return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: This code is awful. It's full of errors like not checking the return value of realloc() before dereferencing or writing sizeof(LPWSTR*) instead of sizeof(*LPWSTR) where LPWSTR seems to be a pointer type and one wants to retrieve the size of one character, not the size of the pointer. Furthermore, it's totally unclear why e.g. case 29 leads to ERROR_DDE_FAIL. Can you conclude from the code why? I can't and I guess anybody else can't, too. Please, do not post such code in the future.

Comment: @Mattew: please in the future help the community by posting a cleaned up version of the code snippet you dislike.

Comment: Code shouldn't be on superuser.  Put it on codereview.se, and just link it from here.

Comment: @user185282: Good points. I've downvoted the answer.

Comment: Dear tao: You wrote, "I cannot remember where we got this code". Did you write this code, or did someone else write it?

Answer (score 3):

A slight improvement on Peon's *fake sudo* script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Drop any option arguments.
while [[ $# -ge 0 && $1 = -* ]]; do
  shift
done

"$@"
```

This script silently drops any options passed to sudo and executes the command (without actually elevating the privileges). Dropping the options  improves compatibility somewhat. A more complete wrapper script should actually parse options the same way sudo does.

Instead of trying to replace sudo with a wrapper that does `cygstart --action=runas "$@"`, just use this simple *fake sudo* wrapper and run your install script itself (or whatever you're trying to run that uses sudo) with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [cygwin-sudo](https://github.com/Chronial/cygwin-sudo) as a drop-in replacement for UNIX/Linux's sudo.

Based on the same principals but one can remain within your current window.

Answer (score 0):

In scripts which can run on linux or windows (cygwin) you can alias out sudo in the script itself:

```
# Alias sudo to do nothing on windows
if ! $(type -P sudo) 
then
  shopt -s expand_aliases
  alias sudo=""
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run sudo but may require options.
If you know the user/group/ Active Dir environment you can supply those as options.

Here is a quick alias or you can "sudo" shell script in common PATH as previous example.

```
alias sudo='runas /noprofile /user:Administrator $@'  
alias sudo-='runas /profile /env /user:Administrator $@'
```

Before you can use "sudo"  you need a running/enabled windows service called "seclogon".

```
cmd /c 'sc config seclogon start=auto'
cmd /c 'sc start seclogon'
```

or use powershell in following link:
[How do I enable services on a Windows computer via a command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/175077/how-do-i-enable-services-on-a-windows-computer-via-a-command-line)