# How do I enable services on a Windows computer via a command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, services

On my Sony Viao pcg-811124 laptop with Windows 7, I disabled all non-Windows services through msconfig.  When I restarted my laptop, it booted up, but I cannot view the screen, even in safe mode. I may have disabled a driver, but now I have no way of knowing which one.

So, not only do I not know which services I disable and need to enable, I can't seem to even enable the services I know that I have (for example, JungleDisk).  When tried to restart it via the command line, I got prompted that I could not restart this service because it had been disabled.

How do I get my services enabled again?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe the command you are looking for is:

> sc config servicenamehere start= auto

You'll need to know the name of the service though - to view this from the command line, try this command - this will show all services:

> sc query type= service state= all

If you want to see *only* stopped services, run this command:

> sc query type= service state= inactive

The list of services output by the query can be quite long. You may filter it by using `findstr` (see [post here](https://superuser.com/questions/300815/grep-equivalent-for-windows-7)) . For example

> sc query type= service state= all | findstr "ssh"

Will select the output lines of the services list that contain the string "ssh"

**Note:** For some services you may need also *administrator privileges*, you will notice it on getting the message `Access is denied` after executing the `sc` command. In that case open the *Command Prompt (Admin)* by pressing 'Windows + X' keys.

Comment: NOTE: the space after the `=` is an essential part of the syntax.

Comment: No it's not, at least not in Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

You can use PowerShell! (To start it, type `powershell` at a normal command prompt.)

The `Get-Service` cmdlet gets a list of services, which you can filter by any property. For example, this gets a list of disabled services:

```
Get-Service | ? {$_.StartType -eq 'Disabled'}
```

The `Set-Service` cmdlet can set several properties of a given service, including the startup type. For example, this sets the `lanmanserver` service to start automatically:

```
Set-Service 'lanmanserver' -StartupType Automatic
```

To make *all* currently disabled services start automatically, use this command:

```
Get-Service | ? {$_.StartType -eq 'Disabled'} | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
```

Comment: Is there any way to check the StartupType of the service before changing it? `Get-Service` doesn't seem to have that info.

Comment: @Shayan The objects returned by `Get-Service` do have a `StartType` property (as I used in my first command), but for some reason it's not shown by default. On PowerShell 5 (and newer, I assume), you can pipe through `select *` to see more properties including `StartType`.