# Grep equivalent for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, grep, cmd.exe

Is there a command prompt [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) equivalent for Windows 7? That is, I want to filter out the results of a command:

**Bash use:**

`ls | grep root`

What would it be from a Windows command prompt?

Comment: don't confuse ms-dos with the command prompt. + use of find and findstr and even grep, for windows.. is surely easily found with a quick search. there are even tables of equivalent commands in linux and windows. also you bash example is not even specific to bash.. just I suppose, *nix OS.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

[Findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) sounds like what you want. I use it all the time as an approximate grep-equivalent on the Windows platform.

[Another example](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/cmd/findstr.html) with pipes:

```
C:\> dir /B | findstr /R /C:"[mp]"
```

Comment: Yeah that seems to be what i'm looking for. I understand there are probably limitations. I'll give it a try.

Comment: why couldn't they just call it grep!

Comment: @VictorGrazi They actually did at first, see [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121128-00/?p=5963/). It was originally named qgrep - but was later renamed.

Comment: The big problem with `findstr` is that the regex pattern may not contain alternatives.

Comment: The question is about Windows 7, but what other versions of Windows have `findstr` by default? [Since Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/300815/grep-equivalent-for-windows-7/300821#300821)?

Comment: @VictorGrazi To not look so similar to Linux.

Comment: What does `/R` and `/C` stands for here?

Comment: `/B`: display only the folder names.
`/R`: Processes search strings as regular expressions. This is the default setting.
`/C`: Uses the specified text as a literal search string.

Comment: from C:\, I type `dir | findstr /R "Progr.F*"` and it finds my two "Program Files" directories. Why does it find them? I only gave one dot.

Comment: But you get some peculiarities like "Piped data and Redirected input is limited to 8191 bytes per line. This limit is a "feature" of FINDSTR."

Answer (score 48):

There are several possibilities:

- **Use a port of a Unix `grep` command.** There are several choices.  Oft-mentioned are [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), and [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).  Less well known, but in some ways better, are the tools in the [SFUA utility toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F), which run in the [Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772343.aspx) that comes right there in the box with Windows 7 Ultimate edition and Windows Server 2008 R2.  (For Windows XP, one can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778) and install [Services for UNIX version 3.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb496506.aspx).)  This toolkit has a large number of command-line TUI tools, from `mv` and `du`, through the Korn and C shells, to `perl` and `awk`.  It comes in both x86-64 and IA64 flavours as well as x86-32.  The programs run in Windows' native proper POSIX environment, rather than with emulator DLLs (such as `cygwin1.dll`) layering things over Win32.  And yes, the toolkit has `grep`, as well as some 300 others.
- **Use one of the many native Win32 `grep` commands that people have written and published.**  Tim Charron has [a native Win32 version of a modified GNU grep](http://pages.interlog.com./~tcharron/grep.html), for example.  There are also [PowerGREP](http://powergrep.com/), [Bare Grep](http://baremetalsoft.com/baregrep/), [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html), [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/), and [dnGrep](http://code.google.com/p/dngrep/), although these are all GUI programs not TUI programs.
- **Use the supplied `find` and `findstr`.**  The syntax is different to that of `grep`, note, as is the regular expression capability.

Comment: cygwin worked for me nicely on Win 7. I needed grep and GnuWin32 grep did not work for me.

Comment: You write  I don't see perl in SUA C:\Windows\SUA>dir perl*  /s/b
File Not Found  and running e.g. c shell of SUA I don't see it in /bin

Comment: you also write that SFUA is in some ways better. In what ways?

Answer (score 28):

If **PowerShell** commands are allowed, use

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem | Select-String root
```

or short

```
PS C:\> ls | sls root
```

Be aware that the alias `sls` is only defined beginning with PowerShell version 3.0. You may add an alias for less typing:

```
PS C:\> New-Alias sls Select-String
```

To run the PowerShell command directly from cmd, use

```
C:\>powershell -command "ls | select-string root"
```

Comment: Grep, the Powershell way.  https://communary.net/2014/11/10/grep-the-powershell-way/

Answer (score 26):

In your early revision you wrote MS-DOS, there's only `FIND`, as far as I know. But it's an ancient OS not used anymore.

In the Windows NT command prompt(e.g. Win2K and win XP and later, so e.g. win7,win10), you can use `find` and `findstr` and if you download [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) then `grep`

The basic differences are that findstr has some [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) support. Grep supports regular expressions best.

```
C:\>dir | find "abc"
C:\>dir | find /i "abc"
```

`find /?` and `findstr /?`shows you what the switches do.

[Gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) has "packages". If you download GnuWin32, I suggest the coreutils package for a bunch of basic useful utilities you'd be familiar with, but grep isn't in that one it's its own package.

**Added**

GnuWin32's grep, last time I checked, is old. Cygwin's grep is far more up to date.  Also bear in mind that many people use Virtual Machines rather than windows ports of *nix commands.

Answer (score 9):

If you would rather use `grep`, rather than `findstr`, there is a single `.exe` file version in [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), so it's portable and there is no need to install it, or use something like Cygwin.

Comment: This is interesting but would require installing that tool.

Comment: @Chris: There is no installation.  It's just a `.zip` file of `.exe` files.  The only small downside is that the versions are slightly old.

Comment: What's the downside of being old? Can software be old? All fresh bytes.

Comment: GnuWin32 also provides `grep` for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Comment: @userunknown well, as an example, the unxutils sed command is older and doesn't support \d e.g. \d22 to specify quote.   An older wget might not download a page that a newer one will, and if you ask for support they may ask that you get the latest one as that can solve some issues. A really old grep no doubt won't have the level of regex support that a current one has

Answer (score 4):

**Bash use**

```
$ ls | grep root
```

**Cmd use**

```
> dir /b | findstr root
```

where `/b` stands for **b**are list of directories and files

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: @DavidPostill: This is fast solution for "TL;DR" users (like me)

Comment: That is no excuse for adding an answer that doesn't contribute anything new. In any case the accepted answer will always appear first so it will be read before yours.

Comment: @DavidPostill, don't mind, but accepted answer contain multiple excessive and **unexplained** keys `/B`, `/R` and `/C` OP didn't ask about, while my answer gives **exact** equivalent

Comment: The `/b` is to make the `dir` output the same as the `ls` output. If you test it you will see the difference. So it is not the exact equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You can try installing [Chocolatey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolatey) on Windows, and through that, install the [Gow](http://chocolatey.org/packages/Gow) tool. This will provide you with `grep` on Windows.

`Gow` stand for GNU on Windows. It provides Unix command line utilities on Windows.

Comment: It's a package manager , like an apt-get but for windows. It got its name 'cos the developer based it off of NuGet which is a package manager for visual studio, and that sounds like nugget (as in chicken nugget), so he thought he'd be "funny" or "clever" and call his program Chocolatey NuGet .  I heard that on a podcast that interviewed him. Gow can be downloaded independently too

Comment: I am new to Gow, after few days of usage I can testify that I like it a lot - it is better than all the older ports of UNIX utils that I had used before.

Comment: @RadimCernej  your comment isn't useful unless you state **how** you think it is better.

Comment: @barlop: Since I wrote my Jan-2016 comment I gradually and completely switched to Gow. So far no bugs, it has all the utilities that I need/use, path are output in Microsoft format (making it easy to copy/paste to other programs). Gow is non-invasive enough (easy to install and remove) that I strongly recommend that you test-drive it.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a Windows alternative to grep using Hybrid Batch/JScript code. I wrote this because getting the escape characters right in the GNU Win32 grep port was a real pain. This version works much more like how you would want the GNU version to work in Windows:

```js
@set @junk=1 /*
@cscript //nologo //E:jscript %~f0 %*
@goto :eof */

var args=WScript.Arguments, argCnt=args.Length, stdin=WScript.StdIn, stdout=WScript.StdOut;
var replaceSingleQuotes=false, printMatchesOnly=false, matchString, flagString, regex, argDx=0;

if(argCnt==0) {
    throw new Error("You must provide search criteria.");
}

flagString=""
if(argCnt>1) {
    for(var bLoop=true; bLoop&&argDx<argCnt-1; argDx++) {
        switch(args(argDx)) {
        case '-t': replaceSingleQuotes=true; break;
        case '-o': printMatchesOnly=true; break;
        case '-g': flagString+="g"; break;
        case '-i': flagString+="i"; break;
        case '-m': flagString+="m"; break;
        default: bLoop=false; break;
        }
    }
}
if(replaceSingleQuotes) {
    matchString=args(argCnt-1).replace("'", '"');
} else {
    matchString=args(argCnt-1);
}

if(printMatchesOnly) {
    while(!stdin.AtEndOfStream) {
        var sLine=stdin.ReadLine();
        if(flagString.Length) regex=new RegExp(matchString, flagString);
        else regex=new RegExp(matchString);
        var m,matches=[],startDx=0;
        while((m=regex.exec(sLine.substr(startDx))) !== null) {
            stdout.WriteLine(m[0]);
            startDx+=m.lastIndex;
        }
    }
} else {
    if(flagString.Length) regex=new RegExp(matchString, flagString);
    else regex=new RegExp(matchString);
    while(!stdin.AtEndOfStream) {
        var sLine=stdin.ReadLine();
        if(regex.test(sLine)) {
            stdout.WriteLine(sLine);
        }
    }

}
```

You can always find the latest version on my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/krowe/da2a6b021ac891f8e3be) page for this.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.multireplacer.com

Multi replacer program has been prepared so that many functions can be carried out by using
command line parameters. Command line usage is seen below:

```
MultiReplacer [Multi Replacer File] | [Search files] | [Search folders]
[-Subs] [-NoSubs] [-IncPtr=pattern] [-ExcPtr=patterns] [-DestDir=destination]
[-DMAnyTime]
[-DMWithinanhour] [-DMToday] [-DMYesterday] [-DMThisweek] [-DMThismonth]
[-DMThisYear]
[-CDMAfter=date] [-CDMBefore=date] [-MinFileSize=bytes count]
[-MaxFileSize=bytes count]
[-Search=text] [-Case] [-NoCase] [-Regex] [-NoRegex] [-SubMatchText=text]
[-ReplaceText=text]
[-StartSearch] [-StartReplace] [-AutoClose] [-StopAfterMatchThisFile] [-StopAfterMatchAll]
[-ExtractedWordsFile=filename] [-ExtractedLinesFile=filename] [-
ReportFile=filename]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use your familiar `grep` and other Linux commands by downloading this tool [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and add it location to your `PATH` environment variable

Comment: unxutils grep isn't as late as you can get.. unx grep is `2.4.2` but gnuwin32 has a later one    `2.5.4`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [busybox-w32](https://frippery.org/busybox/), since it is only about 500 KB in size and actively maintained.

So that in your case, in the command prompt, it is:

```
busybox ls | busybox grep root
```

You can use `doskey` in a command prompt launch by a batch file to make a command, like:

```
doskey ls="path\to\busybox.exe" ls $*

doskey grep="path\to\busybox.exe" grep $*
```

Then you can use `ls | grep root` on the command prompt.

Comment: it has an android build too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the simplest `grep` to your windows environment, then navigate to `c:\windows\system32` and add a little batch script by using this command:

```
echo findstr %1 > grep.bat
```

Now you can

```
dir | grep notepad.exe
```

which is really a scary mix of shit. So add another batch script for `ls` as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15043472/1037303)

```
echo dir %1 > %systemroot%\system32\ls.bat
```

Now things look a bit familiar

```
ls | grep notepad
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

**findstr** is the command equivalent to **grep**.

You can try using this:

```
ls | findstr root
```

Simplest solution regarding your request, that I've found here so far.

Cheers"

Comment: How is this better than the accepted answer?

Comment: It is just shorter. Anon specified:    ls | grep root

What would it be from a Windows command prompt. It was just a need to change grep to findstr.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo findstr %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 > %systemroot%\grep.cmd
```

That's gonna be quick and dirty equivalent.

```
C:\Windows\system32>dir | grep xwiz
C:\Windows\system32>findstr xwiz
2009.06.10  23:03             4.041 xwizard.dtd
2009.07.14  03:39            42.496 xwizard.exe
2009.07.14  03:41           432.640 xwizards.dll
```

Comment: By the way, this dull answer has 44 upvotes on famous russian dev blog https://habrahabr.ru/post/71568/