# Create a Batch file (.bat) to search an string through multiple files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, search, batch-file

I am using Windows Server 2008 and I need to create a Batch file (.bat) to search for a given string in 20.000 to 30.000 files located all in one folder in the same level (without subfolders).

I have been searching and reading around but I couldn't find anything to do it.

Trying it with this without success:

```
@echo off for /r "delims=|" %%i in (*) do  (    
    findstr /m /C:"34444" %%i

)
```

Comment: This should point you at the commandline tools you'd need to use, depending on what you're looking for it should only take one command, shouldn't need a batch file: http://superuser.com/questions/300815/command-prompt-msdos-windows-7-grep-equivalent

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From batch

```
START cmd.exe /k "Findstr -m "34444" *.*"
```

From command line

```
Findstr -m "34444" *.*"
```

also from powershell,
create named batch file *.cmd extension containing following content. (remember to change the gci path 'your folder path'.

```
@PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -noexit -Command Invoke-Expression $('$args=@(^&{$args} %*);'+[String]::Join(';',(Get-Content '%~f0') -notmatch '^^@PowerShell.*EOF$')) & goto :EOF
gci -path 'c:\your folder path\' -fi '*' | Select-String -patt "34444" | select Filename, LineNumber | Format-Table -a
```

call batch file *.cmd to run the powershell search.