# Best way to search for a string (text) in >10 large CSV files (250mb each)

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, search, csv

I am wondering what's the best way or tool to search for a specific text or string in more than 10 large .csv files. Each file is 250mb in size.

My idea was to write a powershell script, since I love selfmade stuff on the other hand there is maybe a perfect tool already and I only waste my time :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try a version of [Grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep):

> Grep is a command-line utility for searching plain-text data sets for lines matching a regular expression.

[This](https://superuser.com/a/301075/337631) answer by JdeBP lists a number of Windows versions of Grep.

I like and use the [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) toolset ...

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell has [Select-String](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) which will search through text files for a regular expression:

```
Get-Item path\to\*.csv | Select-String -Pattern <string>
```

You can use the `-SimpleMatch` switch to search for a literal string. All lines that match your search pattern are shown.

If you want to do more advanced filtering, you can also use [Import-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) to convert a CSV file to objects, with properties for each column.