# Finding a file in a hard drive without knowing name, only contents?

Tags: windows-search, file-search

I need to search a hard drive for a file, but I don't know the name of the file. I only know that the file contains a list of email addresses. (I don't know which email addresses are on the file, I just know that there is a list of email addresses) The file is not necessarily a Word or .txt document. Is there any way that I can find this file? Thanks for the help!

(I have a Windows computer)

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-on-windows-7

Comment: After the index is rebuilt with file contents, as mentioned in the comment above, you could search something like `*@*.com` or `*@*.*` if you do not know the domain.

Comment: Apparently you can't use multiple wildcards in Windows search so something like `content: *.com` would work if you know it ends in `.com`. Otherwise, just change the ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep for windows (in that answer there are several download options - https://superuser.com/a/301075/321990).

An example command that will match (it will search for a regex match recursively from where it's executed):
`grep -r -E ".+\@.+\..+" *`

The file matched contains this:
ariel@gmail.com
ariel@hello.com
lalala@kuku.com
pipi
nana
anilopo$a8

It will print you the 3 email lines, near the file name. It will look like this:
`new/yo.txt:ariel@gmail.com`
Where yo.txt is the file containing the strings above, and located under 'new' folder

If you only want the filenames, you can add the `-l` parameter to grep:
`grep -l -r -E ".+\@.+\..+" *`
And it will only print:
`new/yo.txt`

The regular expression I've used is very simple, and likely to find more things, cause it's not accurate. You can search the web for a better regular expression to check email addresses, and change `".+\@.+\..+"` with what you've found.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've never used this site before, can't believe how fast you get an answer.