# Can't execute .bat file via SSH on Windows server if script contains `taskkill` command

Tags: windows, ssh, batch-file

I have a `.bat` file that I am allowed to run on a Windows Server when connected via Remote Desktop. I am however not able to run that .bat file when connected via `ssh` client. *I am using the same user/credentials for both connections*.

The error message says:

```
coopr@WIN-3PI2FA523CJA89 C:\Users\Coopr\Server\Startup>StopCoopR.bat
ERROR: Access denied
```

The Script does the following:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\Coopr\Server\

taskkill /IM CoopR.exe /F
```

Might it be that `taskkill` has some special behaviour when it comes to remote access?

Comment: `echo` and `cd` are internal commands, but `taskkill` is not (meaning its a separate executable); perhaps you need to provide its full path?

Comment: the full path of taskkill?

Comment: Yes, usually it's at `C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe`; perhaps you can write `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe`...

Comment: coopr@WIN-3PI2OSCJA89 C:\Users\Coopr\Server\Startup>%SystemRoot%\System32\taskki
ll.exe /IM CoopR.exe /F
ERROR: Access denied
- still denied :(

Comment: Did you try runas command or psexec?

Comment: also refer to this question https://superuser.com/questions/181581/how-can-i-run-something-as-administrator-via-cygwins-ssh