# Problem using sudo on cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, sudo

I am trying to install the `python-brisa` framework on Linux. When I try to use the `sudo` command, it gives me the error "command not found".

I am running the following commands:

```
$ cd file
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just cd file then enter, and after that you can run the sudo command.

Comment: The text was on one line because of a formatting issue, not because it was one line of text

Comment: After editing his post, I could see that it seems he did it already.

Comment: which linux are you using, some distro's use su instead of sudo

Comment: I also did the same way....cd python-brisa and then enter...and then type the next line and hit enter....then error appears

Comment: I am using Cygwin

Comment: Looking at the last question posted by the OP, it looks like the OP is on Windows? Have you installed linux? This question should be moved to another stack exchange site as this isn't programming but administration. EDIT: OP added comment before I finished mine =)

Comment: yes...i installed linux -cygwin for windows so that I can run my code on windows also.

Comment: Ubuntu has a very user friendly installer, why not give it a shot?

Comment: You may be able to install the framework but I see that their applications "Media Server" and "Media Renderer" require dbus so if you need these applications it'll be pretty tricky to use windows.

Comment: I dont have any other option...do you know any other framework that can be run on windows via cygwin

Comment: I need to use only python

Comment: what is ubuntu??would it work with python brisa??

Comment: sir...where u gone??please suggest me what to do?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu should work, if you need a linux distribution at this time it is probably the best bet for you.  It can install along side windows in such a way you can use the winodws add/remove programs to uninstall. I think due to performance reasons you may want a more typical install. See: www.ubuntu.com but please do a little research to know what it is that you need to do and what this will get you!

Comment: but? what would happen then?/

Comment: What would happen, you'd be able to use python brisa... Ubuntu is a distribution (a collection of software to keep it simple) of Linux. It's very simple to install from there you'll need to investigate. Further questions should be directed to forums which specialize in this line of questions (Ubuntu forums or an appropriate stack exchange site).

Comment: ok..bit it can work on windows ...right?

Comment: It is an operating system. Generally on a system with multiple OS's you pick the one you want to start from a list. Or you could load Linux in something like Virtual box, so it would be a window _in_ windows... Or you could load windows in a window in Linux... So you could say 'in' or 'beside' but not really 'on'. As an OS is typically viewed as a platform. Really now Google is your friend.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use *sudo* on Cygwin.  Cygwin is restricted to the rights of the security context in which it is executed.

You likely don't need superuser rights to install the package.  Simply run the command without *sudo* and it will probably work.

If you truly need administrator rights, you will need to right-click on the Cygwin icon and choose *Run as administrator* to run Cygwin with administrative privileges.

Answer (score 1):

[Patches](https://superuser.com/a/241500/40916) is right of course, there is no "sudo". But you can make one as shown by answers to many other similar questions. For example [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/699281/40916). Personally I use an alias:

```
alias sudo="cygstart --action=runas"
```

Works as a charm for external programs (not shell built-ins, though):

```
sudo chown User:Group <file>
```