# Pseudo- Sudo on Cygwin/bash

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, cygwin

I need sudo to work, well not sudo itself but a way of allowing the sudo commands to work as [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/122418/theres-no-sudo-command-in-cygwin).

This would be great however the sudo lines have extra arguments, like :

```
sudo -u user bash -c 'uptime'
```

And if I were to use the bash in the link above I simply get the output

```
/usr/bin/sudo: line 3: -u: command not found
```

Is there anyway around this? To make it run from the quote, instead of perhaps -c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the command that's sent will always look exactly like

```
sudo -u user command...
```

then your fake sudo script can just throw out its first two arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
shift 2
exec "$@"
```

Otherwise, you have to do a little argument parsing:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts :u: opt
do
  # normally you'd process options and arguments here,
  # but in this case just ignore them
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))  # throw out processed options and arguments
exec "$@"
```

`getopts` reads and returns command-line options and arguments, until there are no more.  You can read about it in bash(1) (`man bash`) if you want to know more about how to process the command-line arguments.

Comment: The lines are sent remotely, and they're in that format. The user they run from is not important in this case, just need the rest to execute

Comment: OK, I see.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for sudo to run Ansible under babun:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0

for var in "$@"
  do
    (( count++ ))
  done

shift $count
exec "$@"
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `$#` for the count. `#`  Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.