# Sudo access in cygwin

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [there's no sudo command in cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/122418/theres-no-sudo-command-in-cygwin)

How to get root access in cygwin? I tried sudo it is not working and i also found this "$@" command. I am not sure how to use this. Could you please provide me how to use it or any alternative way to obtain sudo access in cygwin.