# how to solve error sudo command is not found in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, sudo

I want to install a game in Windows using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). When trying to use the `sudo` command, I receive the following error:

`-bash:sudo:command not found`

I get a similar error when trying to use command `add-apt-repository`:

`unable to start "add-apt-repository" this specified file was not found`

Why are these commands not recognized?

Comment: apt-get is Debian specific and afaik Cygwin uses it's own repos. Also install sudo via Cygwin installer. Be warned that what you want might not work, you definitely need to recompile the program you want to execute if it hasn't been already compiled for cygwin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There's no 'sudo' command in Cygwin](http://superuser.com/questions/122418/theres-no-sudo-command-in-cygwin)

Comment: The cygin package manager is [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)

Answer (score 2):

You may have misunderstood what Cygwin is useful for. From their website:

`Cygwin is not: a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows.`

Packages like `sudo` do not exist in Cygwin. You can find available packages [here](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi).

They also have a detailed [FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.what.what) that plainly describes what it is, how it can be used, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think I tried steps below after doing some research & succeeded (on Windows)

1. Install scoop using powershell 3
   `iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')`
2. Do `scoop install --global sudo`
3. Make sure paths (`C:\Users\<username>\scoop\shims` & `C:\ProgramData\scoop\shims`) added in environmental path variable.

Comment: I don’t see how this is related to the question...? It’s about Cygwin, not PowerShell or CMD.